# Dynamically apply section padding based on content and viewport height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a single-page, scrolling site broken up into five sections each with a simple, tiled background. For the sake of taller screens, I'm calculating viewport height and then adding a min-height to the sections like so:

```
$('section').css({'min-height': viewportHeight + 'px'});
```

If I want the standard padding (top and bottom) to be 100px, I can set that in CSS and subtract 200 from the min-height function above, but what I'd like to do, instead, is check if the height of each section is less than viewport height minus 200px (the standard padding) and if it is (which means it will have a lot of extra space beneath it), conditionally apply padding that is half of viewport height minus the height of the section. Here's what I'm trying to describe, but you'll have to excuse my jQuery ineptitude:

```
$('.home-top,.home-menu,.home-gallery,.home-press,.home-info').each(function(){
    if(($(this).height) < (viewportHeight - 200)) {
        $(this).css({'padding': (viewportHeight - $(this).height())/2 + 'px ' + 0 'px'})
    } else {
        $(this).css({'padding': (100 + 'px ' + 0 'px'})
    }
});
```

If, for example, the viewport were 1000px tall and a particular section is only 250px, then the padding would be (1000 - height of content)/2 or "padding: 350px 0". Any tall section that doesn't match this criteria would just get "padding: 100px 0".

Not sure if this makes sense, but, I'm, essentially, just trying to vertically center dynamic height content within the sections while setting a minimum height so that even the shortest section's background still fits the entire height of a visitor's screen. Thanks!

Comment: IMO, your overthinking this, It looks like you want responsive columns that match the same height, if this is the case I can help ya, but this seems easier to do with CSS.

Comment: Well, the sections aren't so much content divs as full screen wrappers using the section element. They're the full width/height of the screen, but stacked, that's why I mention it being a scrolling, single-page design. This layout is what makes absolute positioning, table-cell and other CSS hacks unusable (unless I'm missing something). My design is [something like this](http://www.barrelny.com/24/), only I'm trying to get the main content div to vertically center inside each section as every section will fill the viewport.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle for us

Comment: Sure thing. Only the first bit of JS is correct. I'm sure the rest is way off: http://jsfiddle.net/YFegv/

Comment: I believe this is your problem.   if(($(this).height) < (viewportHeight - 200)). I think this is one solution, but im not sure,  if($(this).height < viewportHeight - 200)

Comment: Got it to where it's applying the 100px top/bottom padding, but it seems to be adding this for every section. I must have written the first part of the conditional incorrectly. Tried verifying the calculated heights using console.log(), but couldn't get it to work - the output was "feature ()".

Comment: Updated the fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/seankmchenry/qYJ8E/26/